# Division accuracy

Tags: double, precision

I am programming in c/c++ and want to minimize the truncation error in my calculations. Let's take a look at following example:

```
double test
test=1./6.;
```

Is it already calculating in the right precision or is it doing the calculation in float and casting it in the end to double?
Would the correct way be

```
test= double(1)/double(6);
```

?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add C and C++ TAGS to your question

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.4.4.2 Floating constants 4 An unsuffixed floating constant has type double. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has
type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double.* C++14 draft standard n3797: *2.14.4
Floating literals 1 [...]The type of a
floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes
l and L specify long double.[...]*